# Moving the array/string in reverse

Tags: android, arrays

I have few images and two buttons. I am changing my image views with the help of two buttons, Next and Back. My next button is working fine it changes the images in the forward arrangement, whereas I want my back button to take the arrangement in the reverse direction. It works for a while but when it reaches the first image in the array the app crashes. Here is my code:

```
    private int[] drawables = { R.drawable.bg, R.drawable.green,
            R.drawable.blue };
    private int clicks = 0;
    private int clicks1 = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.learn_main);

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        // INITIALIZING OVER

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (clicks < drawables.length - 1) {
                    clicks++;

                } else {

                    clicks = 0;
                }
                img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks]);
            }

        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (clicks1 < drawables.length + 1) {
                    clicks1++;

                } else {

                    clicks1 = 0;
                }
                img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks1]);
            }

        });

    }
}
```

logcat

```
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.duh.Learn$2.onClick(Learn.java:60)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-28 09:56:31.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried my best to explain my problem in detail, if I didn't do it correctly do let me know I will edit my question for that matter.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the crash? Also, why do you need two counters?  and why are you incrementing the *back counter*

Comment: Back counter because it should reverse the images from their current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution to your problem
declare variable int index = 0; then inside oncreate write code below and you are done

```
    img.setImageResource(drawables[index]);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (index < drawables.length-1) {
                index++;

            } else {

                index = 0;
            }
            img.setImageResource(drawables[index]);
        }

    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (index > 0) {
               index--;

            } else {

                index = drawables.length-1;
            }
            img.setImageResource(drawables[index]);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Single Variable int  clicks=0

```
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (clicks < drawables.length-1) {
              img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks++]);

            }

        }

    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                clicks--;
            if (clicks>=0) {
               img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks]);

            } 

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to comment but my reps is 41 so, See the back button functionality your giving clicks1++, but drawables.length = 3 and +1 ur doing so its 4..So when clicks1 = 2 it will come inside if and do clicks1++ and when it tries to set drawable(clicks1)[that is drawable[3]] it will be out of bound coz drawable[2] is the last element available... Change ur logic..

Answer (score 0):

*Use the below tested code*

```
int clicks = -1

            btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (clicks < drawables.length - 1) {
                        clicks++;
                        img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks]);
                    } 

                }

            });

            btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (clicks > 0) {
                        clicks--;
                        img.setImageResource(drawables[clicks]);
                    } 

                }

            });
```